# Задача коммивояжера

Tags: java, комбинаторика

Помогите, пожалуйста, оптимизировать код полного перебора, чтобы отсекать ненужные нам пути, например есть след. матрица:

```
123
456
789
```

возможные комбинации:

```
1+4+7 1+4+8 1+4+9
1+5+7 1+5+8 1+5+9
1+6+7 1+6+8 1+6+9

2+4+7 2+4+8 2+4+9
2+5+7 2+5+8 2+5+9
2+6+7 2+6+8 2+6+9

3+4+7 3+4+8 3+4+9
3+5+7 3+5+8 3+5+9
3+6+7 3+6+8 3+6+9
```

Т.к. задача коммивояжера предполагает, что мы проходим через 1 город (в данном случае элемент массива) 1 раз, то следующие маршруты нам не подходят:

Маршрут не может проходить через элемент i==j (i - строка в матрице, j - столбец)

```
1+4+7 1+4+8 1+4+9
1+5+7 1+5+8 1+5+9
1+6+7 1+6+8 1+6+9
```

След. элементы имеют индексы (0;1)(1;0)(2;0)

```
2+4+7
```

в данном случае мы не проходим все точки/города/элементы массива, т.к. создан замкнутый цикл.

Помогите оптимизировать след. код, чтобы я получал только валидные пути или подскажите как это реализовать.

```
public boolean next(final int pos) {
        if ( m_Array_Index_1[pos] == m_maxIndex ) {
            if ( pos == 0 ) {
                return false;
            }
            m_Array_Index_1[pos] = 0;
            return next(pos - 1);
        }
        m_Array_Index_1[pos]++;
        return true;
    }
```

С помощью данного кода мы получаем индекс столбцов.

```
pos - строка, где перебираем индексы столбцов.
```

Comment: А почему не может проходить через i==j?
1+5+4+7+8+9+6+3+2+1
полный путь в первую вершину.
Как у вас задается возможность перехода между вершинами? Есть какое-нибудь описание графа?

Comment: Это условие задачи коммивояжера, подробнее здесь https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%97%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B0_%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BC%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%BE%D1%8F%D0%B6%D1%91%D1%80%D0%B0